# How to send a FlexRay Data in CAPL

Tags: embedded, can-bus, capl

I wish to send a FlexRay data on the bus with the help of CAPL. Whenever I'm sending, I'm getting an error.

> (System    14-0002 FlexRay 1: Unable to map PDUs for frame 38(0, 1)A, driver status = 267).

How to send the data on the bus?

I tried to send a message in Canalyzer version 11.0.3, Flexray Slot ID was 38 and Flags were set as 0x10. message channel and channel mask were set as 1. I used froutputDynFrame library function.

Note: I dint use XML file (FlexRay database) for this.

```
includes
{

}

variables

{

  frFrame (38,0,1) dummymsg;

}

on preStart

{

  //dummymsg.fr_slotID=38;


  dummymsg.fr_channelMask=1;


  dummymsg.msgChannel = 1;

  dummymsg.fr_flags=0x10;

}

on key 'a'

{

  byte i = 0;

  dummymsg.byte(i++) = 0x10; // Target Address

  dummymsg.byte(i++) = 0x11;

  dummymsg.byte(i++) = 0x12; // Source Address

  dummymsg.byte(i++) = 0x13;

  dummymsg.byte(i++) = 0x10;

  dummymsg.byte(i++) = 0x00;

  dummymsg.byte(i++) = 0x05;

  dummymsg.byte(i++) = 0x10;

  dummymsg.byte(i++) = 0x12;

  dummymsg.byte(i++) = 0x34;

  dummymsg.byte(i++) = 0x56;

  dummymsg.FR_PayloadLength = 4;

  froutputDynFrame(dummymsg);

}
```

if the key 'a' is pressed, the data should fall on the bus without errors.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the schedule. You do need to have Fibex database file or at least proper configuration of your static/dynamic segmentation on the bus.

Only frames in the dynamic segment can be sent using this function `frOutputDynFrame`
For static segment use `frUpdateStatFrame`

To check that you are able to send frames/PDUs you can just Insert FlexRay Frame Panel (or PDU Panel) in the simulation setup.

Comment: so the CAPL function `output(dummymsg)` (which can be used to send CAN messages), will not work with sending Flexray messages?